# Node directory listing with sizes

Tags: windows, node.js, directory

I have a flat (single directory) on a windows 7 server, that I populate with files, and then need to get all the PNG files (name & size) and  then the total size. I have been doing this with C#.

```
private void CreateManifest()
{
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(jobPath);
    string id;
    long size;

    foreach (var f in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.png"))
    {
        id = f.Name.Replace(".png", "");
        size = f.Length;
        manifest.files.Add(new FileData(id, size));
        manifest.FileCount++;
        manifest.Size += size;
    }
}
```

Since there might be a few thousand files, I need this to be fast. I could use the EDGE module ( https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) to call a the .NET directly from Node. [if you have tried EDGE, I recommend it. It is a great way to include native .NET C#, F#, and python into your NODEJS project with full async callback support and object marshalling].

Is there a native NODE technique? and which one would be the fastest?

I am tempted to do a fs.readdir and the fs.lstat() all the files (see: https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/how-to-list-files-and-folders-using-nodejs/ )

I have also seen some directory walker programs, which might be good: https://github.com/oleics/node-filewalker

But what I really need is fast performance on a windows box.

[background: this is the post-processing phase of generation  (child_Process ) of a pyramid of 256x256 map tiles from raw imagery, and the amount of files can be quite large].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, readdir and lstat is the fastest way I can think of. The only extra thing here in my example is a library called async, which lets us run all of our lstat calls in parallel.

```js
var fs = require('fs'); // native fs module
var async = require('async'); // async node module (npm install async)

var manifest = {
    files: []
  , size: 0
}
var directory = __dirname; // just an example

// returns a list of filenames in the directory
fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {

  //Run for each file in files
  async.forEach(files, function(file, callback) {

    // Check file extension
    if (file.substr(file.lastIndexOf(".")) == ".png") {

      // stat file (size is in this)
      fs.lstat(directory + "/" + file, function(err, data) {

        // Update our manifest object with new data
        manifest.size += data.size;
        manifest.files.push({
            name: file.substr(0,file.lastIndexOf(".")) //filename without .png
          , size: data.size
        });

        // Let async know this file is done
        callback(err);
      });
    }
    else {
      // Let async know this file is done
      callback();
    }
  },
  function(err) { //This is only called after all files have fired their 'callback'
    console.log(err);
    console.log('files', manifest.files);
    console.log('file count', manifest.files.length);
    console.log('total size', manifest.size);
  });
});
```

If you have any questions about this code, feel free to ask.

Comment: Excellent, you did not have to write it for me! all I needed was a pointer. I actually did this myself yesterday, and yes, I used async. Performance is quite good.

Comment: one point, I think it is lodash that has the _.forEach(), and the async module has an .each (https://www.npmjs.org/package/async), I also used a "//" after the directory, see below.

Comment: Async has support for both, with `forEach` as an alias for `each` ([async.js#L125](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L125))

The slash can go either way on windows node, but I wasn't sure how `\\ ` would behave on unix systems so I stuck to `/` in case others referenced my example. :)

Comment: Are you educating me? I.e. What I should really be doing is path.join(directory, file)

Comment: I was just giving my reasons for why I used the forward slash. At least in my brief testing `path.join` is about 3x slower than just concatenating strings, but they are still both really really fast and it doesn't matter which one you are using. If you are doing it thousands of times though its better to concatenate if you can trust your paths not to contain random things like objects or nulls.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I got working:

```
function tileList(job, callback) {
var tiles = [];
var byteCount = 0;
fs.readdir(job.root, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        logger.log('error', 'tileList directory read: %s \n', job.root, { message: err.message, stack: err.stack });
        return job.next(err);
    }
    async.each(files, function (file, done) {
        var fileName = file.split(".");
        fs.lstat(job.root + "\\" + file, function (err, stats) {
            if (!err && stats.isFile() && (fileName[1] == "png")) {
                tiles.push({ id: fileName[0], size: stats.size });
                byteCount += stats.size;
            };
            done(null);
        });
    }, function (err) {
    job.tileList = tiles;
    job.byteCount = byteCount;
    return callback(null, "got tile list");}
    );
});
```

}